# Неравномерное распределение при использовании Random

Tags: java

Например, есть строковый массив:

```
String[] a = { "1", "2", "3" };
```

Как заставить класс `Random` генерировать соответствующие значения, если вероятности выпадения должны быть такими: `1 = 20%` , `2 = 35%`, `3 = 45%`?

Comment: Если случайное число попадает в диапазон от 0 до 0.2, то выдавать первое значение, от 0.2 до 0.55 - второе, в остальных случаях третье.

Comment: Автору вопроса. Если ответ вам подходит, примите его как верный (зелёная галочка слева).

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov так надо же было спустя месяц уже бить тревогу, уже бы давно ответили

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы можете самостоятельно задать вероятности:

```
int[] probabilities = { 20, 55, 100 };
```

(`20, 20+35, 20+35+45` используются для удобства счета), после чего выбирать нужную строку с помощью массива вероятностей и `rand.nextInt(100)`:

```
private static final String[] values = { "a", "b", "c" };
private static final int[] probabilities = { 20, 55, 100 };
private static final Random rand = new Random();

private static String get()
{
    int number = rand.nextInt(100);
    int resultIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++)
    {
        if (number < probabilities[i])
        {
            resultIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return values[resultIndex];
}
```

То есть генерируется случайное число от `0` до `99`, после чего с помощью сравнения проверяется к какому варианту оно подходит: значения от `0` до `19` (20 из 100) подпадают под первый вариант (`"a"`), от `20` до `54` (35 из 100) - под второй, и от `55` до `99` (45 из 100) - под третий.

---

Вместо целых чисел можно использовать и дробные. Например, вместо процентов использовать значения самих вероятностей, которые находятся в диапазоне от `0` до `1`. В этом случае в коде нужно изменить две строки:

```
private static final double[] probabilities = { 0.2, 0.55, 1.0 };
```

и

```
double number = rand.nextDouble();
```

---

В проведённом тесте:

```
Map<String, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
{
    String str = get();
    test.putIfAbsent(str, 0);
    test.put(str, test.get(str) + 1);
}
System.out.println(test);
```

Результаты весьма близки к заданным вероятностям:

```
{a=199844, b=349856, c=450300}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь !!!)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] x = {"a", "b", "c"}; 
    Double [] y = {0.23, 0.27, 0.5};

    Random rand = new Random();
    Double number = rand.nextDouble();

    int Index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
    {
        if (number <= y[i])
        {
            Index = i;
            break;
        }
        y[i + 1] += y[i];
    }

    System.out.println(x[Index]);
}
```